# Monte Carlo Cross Validation coding problem in R - Auto MPG dataset

Tags: r, error-handling, cross-validation

I'm just practicing Monte Carlo Cross Validation coding problem in R, using Auto MPG dataset.

After practicing classifying tools, I just want to apply cross validation, setting B = 100.
However, I am just stopped by some coding errors in my R codes like below;

Error in mean(predict(mod1.CV, Auto_test.CV) != Auto_test.CV$mpg01) :
'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'

Warning: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object lengthWarning: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length[1]

Please let me know where to alter the codes properly. Thanks!

```
full = rbind(Auto_train, Auto_test)
n1 = 274
set.seed(123)
n = dim(full[1])
B = 100
TEALL = NULL

for (b in 1:B){
  flag <- sort(sample(1:n,n1))
  Auto_train.CV <- full[flag,]
  Auto_test.CV <- full[-flag,]
  CV.test.err <- NULL
  
  mod1.CV <- lda(mpg01 ~ cylinders + displacement + horsepower + weight, data = Auto_train.CV)
  pred1.CV <- predict(mod1.CV, Auto_train.CV)$class
  CV.test.err <- cbind(CV.test.err, mean(predict(mod1.CV, Auto_test.CV) != Auto_test.CV$mpg01))
  
  mod2.CV <- qda(mpg01 ~ cylinders + displacement + horsepower + weight, data = Auto_train.CV)
  pred2.CV <- predict(mod2.CV, Auto_train.CV)$class
  CV.test.err <- cbind(CV.test.err, mean(predict(mod2.CV, Auto_test.CV) != Auto_test.CV$mpg01))
  
  mod3.CV <- naiveBayes(mpg01 ~ cylinders + displacement + horsepower + weight, data = Auto_train.CV)
  pred3.CV <- predict(mod3.CV, Auto_train.CV)
  CV.test.err <- cbind(CV.test.err, mean(predict(mod3.CV, Auto_test.CV) != Auto_test.CV$mpg01))

  mod4.CV <- multinom(mpg01 ~ cylinders + displacement + horsepower + weight, data = Auto_train.CV)
  pred4.CV <- predict(mod4.CV, Auto_train.CV)
  CV.test.err <- cbind(CV.test.err, mean(predict(mod4.CV, Auto_test.CV) != Auto_test.CV$mpg01))
 
  train.X.CV <- cbind(Auto_train.CV$cylinders, Auto_train.CV$displacement, Auto_train.CV$horsepower, Auto_train.CV$weight)
  test.X.CV <- cbind(Auto_test.CV$cylinders, Auto_test.CV$displacement, Auto_test.CV$horsepower, Auto_test.CV$weight)
  mod5.CV <- knn(train.X.CV, test.X.CV, Auto_train.CV$mpg01, k = 4)
  CV.test.err <- cbind(CV.test.err, mean(mod5.CV != Auto_test.CV$mpg01))
  
}

TEALL = rbind(TEALL, CV.test.err))
```

Comment: Welcome! The `predict()` function differs depending on the model you create. It looks like you are trying to predict data with existing values from the `Auto_train.CV` dataset. Usually, you will define those values in the `newdata` parameter of `predict()`.